# Kubuntu 19.10: Issue with internal B&O (Bang and Olufsen) speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hp, speakers

First of all, I am aware that this problem is very widespread and still hasn't been fixed, despite it being *years* old. I am also aware that this question is a duplicate of tens of other questions like this one. And I am not very erudite in the terminology of soundcards and everything.

My machine:

- HP Pavilion cw-1010-ur
- Kubuntu 19.10 64-bit
- Kernel version 5.3.0-29-generic
- AMD processor and integrated GPU

My laptop has built-in B&O (Bang and Olufsen) speakers. **On Windows 10**, even without the auto-installed drivers, **the speakers work as intended** (no static or silent channels or anything). On Kubuntu the speakers don't work at all:

(READ THIS)

Using `pavucontrol` I was able to determine that sound is being sent to the speakers just fine (the volume sliding indicator was changing constantly - a sign of music playing), but the speakers were completely silent. Then I noticed that the speakers port says "Speakers (***unavailable***)". The B&O speakers are not recognized by the system.

(READ ABOVE)

The soundcard chip is ACL295 Analog.

**I want help getting the Kubuntu OS to recognize my B&O speakers**. If you want to send a link to one of the duplicate questions, don't. I have foraged through many such questions, on arch/mint/ubuntu/manjaro forums. None of the few solutions listed there worked for me.

Now here is why I started writing this question: I *think* that the issue is not with Kubuntu. It is just that between the Realtek ACL295 chip and the speakers there is actually *a third chip*, most likely of B&O production, that Kubuntu cannot communicate with. Again, I *think* this might be the case. If it is, then there is nothing we can do. If not, and you think you have a solution that might work, then please do share it here. Thank you.